# How to set up multiple HTTPS connections in Java

Tags: java, https

I'm using HTTPS to connect to web services. The problem is that I need to connect to 2 web services and then they have different certificates. In this class there is this code:

```
public static synchronized SocketFactory getFactory(String protocol, 
                                                    Hashtable attributes) {
     SocketFactory theFactory = (SocketFactory) factories.get(protocol);
     if (theFactory == null) {
         Object[] objects = { attributes };
         if (protocol.equalsIgnoreCase("http")) {
             theFactory = (SocketFactory) AxisProperties.newInstance(
                     SocketFactory.class, classes, objects);
         } else if (protocol.equalsIgnoreCase("https")) {
             theFactory = (SecureSocketFactory) AxisProperties.newInstance(
                     SecureSocketFactory.class, classes, objects);
         } 
         if (theFactory != null)
             factories.put(protocol, theFactory); 
         }
    }
    return theFactory;
}
```

If you set up the configuration for HTTPS, and now, you want to set up another configurarion for HTTPS, you cannot do it because the code returns the first configuration.

How can I solve it?

Comment: This is only a problem if one or both of them have self-signed certificates, or certificates whose signers are not trusted by the Java keystore: in which case the solution is not to write code but to use a custom keystore that contains the certificates you need to trust.

Comment: I have 2 JKS. I have one certificate in one of this and another certificate in the another JKS.

Comment: So ... put both certificates into the same JKS.  (I assume you are talking about server certs ...)

Comment: You can have multiple SSLContext and thus multiple SSLSocketFactory instances, one for each configuration.